# Patching an upgraded version

Tags: 16.04, apt, updates

EDIT (ADDED): I am unable to patch after doing do-release-upgrade from 14 to 16. It is very clear that there is a newer kernel and file package based on scanning the security notices, but they are not "seen", thus cannot be applied.

I use debmirror to create a local repo.  It's an older version as I had to run it on Debian 7.

After some fiddling around, I managed to figure out everything I needed to get do-release-upgrade working.  For example, debmirror would not get any of the dist-upgrader-all directories.

So I got a handful of systems to upgrade from 14 to 16, but now I'm stuck.

Is there any kind of breakdown (or extra debugging?) that APT (1.2.29) goes through?

I'm looking at network traces.  I see that `get-apt update` fails to pull down files like "Packages.xz".  Also, debmirror doesn't support any of the by-hash stuff.  Are either of these absolutely required in XENIAL?

I see Packages.gz getting pulled down and also tweaked the repository to also get InRelease files, but `get-apt upgrade` fails:

```
root@FOO:~# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libio-string-perl
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I don't quite know where to start.  Some have mentioned to "restore sources.list", but I do believe this is the expected format, and that this is not my issue.  Here's my client configuration:

```
deb http://my_ip:my_port/ubuntu xenial main
deb http://my_ip:my_port/ubuntu xenial-updates main
deb http://my_ip:my_port/ubuntu xenial-security main
```

The above worked 100% for do-release-upgrade (except for "xenial" replaced with "trusty").

`apt-get update` does list quite a few "Ign" lines, hence some of my questions above about any *additional requirements* in XENIAL, again, since v14 was working.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to patch after doing do-release-upgrade from 14 to 16.  It is very clear that there is a newer kernel and file package based on scanning the security notices, but they are not "seen", thus cannot be applied.

Comment: what does `sudo update-grub` output, and does the problem persist after rebooting after running this command? I still don't know what you mean by "patch"?

Comment: update-grub: root@FOO:~# update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-142-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-142-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.bin
done But...  142 is not the latest. https://usn.ubuntu.com/3910-1/

Comment: As for "patch"...  I'm trying to get security and updated packages applied to the system.

Comment: a thing `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -y` will acomplish, right? I think what's happening is that you are used to old ubuntu 14 syntax (on ubuntu 16 apt may not yet be installed, if not you can run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y`) (don't get mad I'm just trying to remove "Babel" from between us, once I better understand the issue, I might stand a better chance of helping) also out of curiosity from what does this will to be 4.5 versions behind even AFTER an upgrade?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91601/discussion-between-marco-shaw-and-tatsu).